# What is the difference between `finishAffinity();` and `finish()` methods in Android?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-lifecycle

I've using some code for a sign in screen that forces the app to close if the user doesn't want to sign in. If the user chooses to not sign in/cancel, it calls the code to exit the app. I've successfully done this two ways (not at the same time) with:

```java
finishAffinity();
 System.exit(0);
```

**and**

```java
finish();
 System.exit(0);
```

Yet both lines of code seem to do the same thing... The app is closed to the user, yet remains in the background apps to be reopen if the user hits the 'overview' button they can select it to reopen. (Which just restarts the prompt to sign in.)

Since I notice no functional difference, I'm wondering what is the difference between `finishAffinity()` and `finish()` methods?

**Bonus Question:** Also, is there a way to completely shut down the app, so it also doesn't appear in the overview button app list?

Comment: You will find the answer here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**finishAffinity()** :  `finishAffinity()` is not used to "**shutdown an application**". It is used to remove a number of Activities belonging to a specific application from the current task (which may contain Activities belonging to multiple applications).

Even if you finish all of the Activities in your application, the OS process hosting your app does not automatically go away (as it does when you call `System.exit()`). Android will eventually kill your process when it gets around to it. You have no control over this (and that is intentional).

**finish()** : When calling `finish()` in an activity, the method `onDestroy()` is executed this method can do things like:

- Dismiss any dialogs the activity was managing.
- Close any cursors the activity was managing.
- Close any open search dialog.

Comment: So basically the `System.exit(0)` will eventually pop out the app from the recent list as soon as the OS feels like it? And `finishAffinity()` kills the stack and returns user to home screen because it removes backstack of other applications? So how can I make sure the user can't return to my app when cancelling, but not ruin their entire task stack experience up to that point? (b/c this might include coming from a previous app to mine...)

Answer (score 21):

> finishAffinity():

Closes all the activities present in the current Stack

> finish()

Closes only opened activity

> Also, is there a way to completely shut down the app, so it also
>   doesn't appear in the overview button app list?

Yes you can add `android:noHistory="true"` to your `activities tag` in the `Manifest.xml` for this pupose

Comment: Wouldn't `android:noHistory="true"` also mess up normal activity backstacking and thus the intending UI flow because it wouldn't remember any tasks?

Answer (score 5):

finishAndRemoveTask() method pop out all your activities from stack and removes the application from recent task list simple finish this current activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity, 
**finish()** method pop out your current activity from stack.
 for detail document [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finishAffinity())

**finishAffinity()**: finish the current activity and all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity.
**finishAndRemoveTask()**: call this when your activity is done and should be closed and the task should be completely removed as a part of finishing the root activity of the task.

Comment: `finishAndRemoveTask()` for some reason doesn't work in this code to exit the app, it loads the screen before it. (I suppose because it was on a different task stack?)